# How can I fix this expo-cli

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo cli to make react native apps and while i run my app gating an error spawn powershell ENOENT[image: here is my error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciao, seems a problem with Powershell rather than expo-cli. Try to:

1. add Powershell to `PATH` as `%SystemRoot%/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0`;
2. open Powershell as admin and launch this command `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force`;
3. restart pc.

Comment: No problem @GorGevorgyan. If you think answer was helpful, please mark it as valid :)